Capture frame/image from react-native-webrtc stream
Iam using react-native-webrtc to extract frame/image but it's not working,
I tried to use react-native-canvas and react-native-viewshot but it shows blank image on android. Is there anyway to achieve this on both android and ios ?
I need to extract frame
